# C# Escape Plus Sign (+) in POST using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, winforms, post, httpwebrequest, urlencode

I'm having issues to send POST data that includes characteres like "+" in the password field,

```cs
string postData = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}", "anyname", "+13Gt2");
```

I'm using HttpWebRequest and a webbrowser to see the results, and when I try to *log in* from my C# WinForms using HttpWebRequest to POST data to the website, it tells me that password is incorrect. (in the source code[richTexbox1] and the webBrowser1). Trying it with another account of mine, that does not contain '+' character, it lets me log in correctly (using array of bytes and writing it to the stream)

```cs
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData); //get the data
request.Method = "POST"; 
request.Accept = "text/html";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
newStream.Close(); //this works well if user does not includes symbols
```

From this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089177/how-to-escape-url-encoded-data-in-post-with-httpwebrequest) I found that `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` is the solution to escape illegal characters, but I can't find out how to use it correctly, my question is, after url-encoding my POST data with `urlEncode()` how do I send the data to my *request* correctly?

This is how I've been trying for HOURS to make it work, but no luck,
**First method**

```cs
string urlEncoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(postData, ASCIIEncoding.ASCII);
//request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = urlEncoded.Length;
StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(),ASCIIEncoding.ASCII);
wr.Write(urlEncoded); //server returns for wrong password.
wr.Close();
```

**Second method**

```cs
byte[] urlEncodedArray = HttpUtility.UrlEncodeToBytes(postData,ASCIIEncoding.ASCII);
Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
newStream.Write(urlEncodedArray, 0, urlEncodedArray.Length); // Send the data.
newStream.Close();  //The server tells me the same thing..
```

I think I'm doing wrong on how the url-encoded must be sent to the request, I really ask for some help please, I searched through google and couldn't find more info about how to send encoded url to an HttpWebRequest.. I appreciate your time and attention, hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: You dont have to encode post data. In fact, when you encode post data like this, the browser will interpret it wrongly. You probably have a problem with your encoding. Add charset=ISO-8859-1 to your content type and see what happens

Comment: @Polity First thank you for making it clear for me, I couldn't find how to use the urlEncode to escape special characters, I tried what you told me (charset=ISO-8859-1) and still have same results, nothing changed, I believe it's on the encoding, the '+' is converted to a space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found my answer using `Uri.EscapeDataString` it exactly solved my problem, but somehow I couldn't do it with `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`. *Stackoverflowing around*, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602642/server-urlencode-vs-httputility-urlencode) that is about urlEncode method, in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2x4538s.aspx) it documentation tells that:

> **Encodes a URL string.**

But I know now that is wrong if used to encode POST data (@Marvin, @Polity, thanks for the correction). After discarding it, I tried the following:

```cs
string postData = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}", "anyname", Uri.EscapeDataString("+13Gt2"));
```

The POST data is converted into:

```cs
// **Output
string username = anyname;
string password = %2B13Gt2;
```

`Uri.EscapeDataString` in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) says the following:

> **Converts a string to its escaped representation.**

I think this what I was looking for, when I tried the above, I could POST correctly whenever there's data including the '+' characters in the formdata, but somehow there's much to learn about them.

This link is really helpful.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yangxind/archive/2006/11/09/don-t-use-net-system-uri-unescapedatastring-in-url-decoding.aspx

Thanks a lot for the answers and your time, I appreciate it very much. Regards mates.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend you a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx). Will shorten your code and take care of encoding and stuff:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    { 
        { "username", "anyname" },
        { "password", "+13Gt2" },
    };
    var url = "http://foo.com";
    var result = client.UploadValues(url, values);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Darin, but unfortunately the website does not support WebClient, so anytime I do this, I get "this browser is not supported"  However is interesting how it is not needed to set encoding when using WebClient, but I'll try if this works when passing a '+' character. I already found my answer using `Uri.EscapeDataString` Thanks a lot for the useful answer.

Comment: @WhySoSerious, a web site doesn't know what a WebClient is. A web site listens and answers HTTP requests. A WebClient can send HTTP requests. So if the site says that the browser is not supported chances are that this site expects some special User-Agent header to be set in the request. So simply use the Headers property and set the User-Agent HTTP request header to whatever the site you are trying to reach expects.

Answer (score -1):

the postdata you are sending should NOT be URL encoded! it's formdata, not the URL

```
  string url = @"http://localhost/WebApp/AddService.asmx/Add";
  string postData = "x=6&y=8";

  WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
  HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)req;

  httpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
  httpReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  Stream s = httpReq.GetRequestStream();
  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s,Encoding.ASCII);
  sw.Write(postData);
  sw.Close();

  HttpWebResponse httpResp = 
                 (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();
  s = httpResp.GetResponseStream();
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.ASCII);
  Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

This uses the System.Text.Encoding.ASCII to encode the postdata.

Hope this helps,

Comment: This either wont fix the problem or introduces more bugs. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#h-5.2.2 there is no implied encoding in HTML and HTTP implies ISO-8859-1 as the default encoding, not ASCII (which isnt even an encoding in the first place, ask skeet ;))

Comment: Hi @Marvin, thanks for the answer but this is what I did on my code, and this still does not escape '+' character, see that I used it with the `StreamWriter` with the ASCII encoding when trying to "encode" the postData, which is wrong (knowing it from you guys), thanks for your time to answer.