# How to send plus (+) symbol over http?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I would like to know how to send plus symbol (+) over http link because when I try to send it after encoding like this %2B still I am getting empty space. If I try with + I am getting double empty space. Please help me on that.

I am sending like this to the page using the browser:

```
   localhost:/CPA-API/MT.aspx?msg=Testing%2BTesting
```

and receiving from the code behind like this:

```
   msg = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["msg"].ToString());
```

But I am getting output like this:

```
   msg = Testing Testing
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Likely the program receiving it is converting the %2B to a space

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517511/c-sharp-escape-plus-sign-in-post-using-httpwebrequest) may help

Comment: Please check my updated question for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try without urldecode

```
string msg = Request.QueryString["msg"];
string decoded = Server.UrlDecode(msg);
```

result:

```
msg = "Testing+Testing"
decoded = "Testing Testing"
```

Comment: also see msdn page for Request.QueryString: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: When you use parameters with Request.QueryString, the server parses the parameters sent to the request and returns the specified data. If your application requires unparsed QueryString data, you can retrieve it by calling Request.QueryString without any parameters. - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. But now I am trying to send the Euro sign € but I receive b$ with Request.QueryString["msg"] will you please mind to help me one more time?

Comment: sorry but for the url http://localhost:62348/Default.aspx?msg="asdf€" i receive msg="asdf€" and decoded="asdf€"

Comment: maybe thge problem is where you build your query string