# HTTP 400 error when server fires a long http request to another server

Tags: http, urlconnection, http-status-code-400, large-data

I have a scenario where I hit a cacheRefresh.do URL from an HTTP Client.
It reaches App Server A, A refreshes its own cache and then sends a request (I am using URLConnection) to App Server B,to refresh its cache. (I know its a bad design, but we are out of option)

Now when my request is refresh small cache(small response time) , everything looks fine, I get a 200.

But when my request is to refresh large cache, I get a 400.

Server A and B do get refreshed in this case as well, but why do I get a 400 back as response? Any idea ?

Below is the controller code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public ModelAndView handleRequest(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    final long cacheRefreshStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    final String action = request.getParameter("action");
    // Init to 74 since this is the static length that will be appended.
    final StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(74);
    final String[] cacheKeys = request.getParameterValues("cacheKeys");
    String[] cacheElement = request.getParameterValues("cacheElement");
    final String refreshByKeyRegion = request.getParameter("refreshByKeyRegion");
    final String refreshByKeyRegionKeys = request.getParameter("refreshByKeyRegionKeys");
    final String refreshPartnerInstanceCache = request.getParameter("refreshPartnerInstanceCache");
    LOG.debug(" cacheKeys for refresh " + Arrays.toString(cacheKeys));

    try {
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("ALL")) {
            performancLogger.info("Cache Refresh requested action=" + action);
            this.refreshAllCache();
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("SPECIFIC")) {
            performancLogger.info("Cache Refresh requested action=" + action + " keys="
                    + Arrays.toString(cacheKeys));
            this.refreshSpecificCache(cacheKeys);
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("cacheElement")) {
            if (refreshByKeyRegion != null && refreshByKeyRegion.length() > 0 && refreshByKeyRegionKeys != null
                    && refreshByKeyRegionKeys.length() > 0) {
                cacheElement = new String[] { refreshByKeyRegion + "," + refreshByKeyRegionKeys };
            }
            performancLogger.info("Cache Refresh requested action=" + action + " element="
                    + Arrays.toString(cacheElement));
            this.refreshCacheElements(cacheElement);
        }
        if (!request.getServerName().contains("localhost") && refreshPartnerInstanceCache != null
                && refreshPartnerInstanceCache.equals("true")) {
            refreshPartnerInstanceCache(request);
        }
        result.append("Cache refresh completed successfully.");

        if (cacheKeys != null) {
            result.append(" Keys - ");
            result.append(this.formatArrayAsString(cacheKeys));
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        result.append("Cache refresh failed.");
        if (cacheKeys != null) {
            result.append(" Keys - ");
            result.append(this.formatArrayAsString(cacheKeys));
        }
    }

    if (action != null) {
        performancLogger.info("Cache Refresh competed total refresh time = "
                + formatElapsedTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - cacheRefreshStartTime));
    }

    return new ModelAndView(IVRControllerNames.CACHE_REFRESH_STANDARD_VIEW, "displayInfo", this
            .getDisplayInfo(result));
}
```

Request Header:

```
POST xxxxx.do HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxxx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://xxx/yyy/zzz/cacheView.do
Cookie: JSESSIONID=xxxxx.x.x
```

Request Body:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Content-Length: 134 
action=SPECIFIC&refreshPartnerInstanceCache=true&cacheKeys=xxxx&cacheKeys=xxx&Refresh=yyyy
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you post some code of your request and what AppServers do with it?

Comment: @PlínioPantaleão: code snippets added above in the question.Keep in mind, if I send a request to only refresh  2 or 3 caches, it works fine. but if I request for a long processing  (like refresh 7-8 or more caches). That's when I am facing this issue. I believe it has something to do with my initial request getting timedout or something, not sure ?

Answer (score 0):

In your action you seem to have several keys with the same name.

```
action=SPECIFIC&refreshPartnerInstanceCache=true&**cacheKeys**=xxxx&**cacheKeys**=xxx&Refresh=yyyy
```

Clean it up and give them unique IDs.

Also, they do not seem to be urlencoded which may cause trouble if your keys contain funny characters. See [How to escape URL-encoded data in POST with HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089177/how-to-escape-url-encoded-data-in-post-with-httpwebrequest)